# React Form with form data held as Object within Form state - reset not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React Form app with name and description fields.

The form data is held in a local state object using Hooks:

`const [data,setData] = useState({name: '', description: ''})`.

The `<Form />` element creates inputs and passes their value using `<Field initialValue ={data.name} />`

Within the `<Field />` element, this `initialValue` is passed to the state, which controls the input value (updated `onChange`):

`const [value,setValue] = useState(initialValue)`.

**But if I reset the data object (see `handleResetClick` function), the inputs don't clear (even though the data object clears). What am I doing wrong?** I thought that changing the data would cause a re-render and re-pass `initialValue`, resetting the input.

[Codepen example here](https://codepen.io/sarahessex/pen/GRREXvM) - when I type in the inputs, the data object updates, but when I click Clear, the inputs don't empty.

```
function Form() {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState({name: '', description: ''});

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(data);
    },[data]);

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        // not relevant to example
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    const handleResetClick = () => {
        console.log('reset click');
        setData({name: '', description: ''})
    }

    const onChange = (name, value) => {
        const tmpData = data;
        tmpData[name] = value;
        setData({
            ...tmpData
        }); 
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <Field onChange={onChange} initialValue={data.name} name="name" label="Name" />
            <Field onChange={onChange} initialValue={data.description} name="description" label="Description" />
            <button type="submit" className="button is-link">Submit</button>
            <button onClick={handleResetClick} className="button is-link is-light">Clear</button>
        </form>
    )
}

function Field(props) {
    const {name, label, initialValue, onChange} = props;
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="field">
                <label className="label">{label}</label>
                <div className="control">
                        <input
                            name={name}
                            className="input"
                            type="text"
                            value={value}
                            onChange={e => {
                                setValue(e.target.value)
                                onChange(name, e.target.value)
                            }}
                            />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="container">
            <Form />
        </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: Well from my understanding (which may be wrong) `initialValue` is just what I'm calling the property that I am passing down to the `Field`. This property is then passed into the state of the component to value, which is used on the input. You may well be right but I'm not sure how to pass what you are suggesting down to the `Field` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `handleResetClick` you change the `data` state of `Form`, but it doesn't affect its children.

Try adding a listener for `initialValue` change with `useEffect`:

```
function Field(props) {
  const { name, label, initialValue, onChange } = props;
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(initialValue);
  }, [initialValue]);

  return ...
}
```

[image: Edit Q-58579232-FormUseEffect]

Comment: That works! I didn't actually realise you could use useEffect with props because I didn't think props changed. So am I right in understanding that, passing a different property to a component doesn't 're-initialise' it? Only re-renders it? I think that's where my understanding is lacking.

Comment: Yes, passing different props re-renders it (depending on if the component memoized). Note: If you trying to implement a `form` I would like to recommend reading [Controlled vs Uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) components.

Comment: ^ You may want to implement uncontrolled form and collect it data on submit, just suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off having `Field` as a controlled component (ie it's state is managed by the parent component rather than maintaining its own state). In this example I've swapped in `value` instead of `initialValue` and simply passed that down as props to the field. `onChange` then calls the parent method and updates the state there (which is automatically passed back down to the field when it renders):

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function Form() {

  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    name: '',
    description: ''
  });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data);
  }, [data]);
  
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  
  const handleResetClick = () => {
    setData({name: '', description: ''})
  }
  
  const onChange = (e) => {
    const { target: { name, value } } = e;
    setData(data => ({ ...data, [name]: value }));
  }
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <Field onChange={onChange} value={data.name} name="name" label="Name" />
      <Field onChange={onChange} value={data.description} name="description" label="Description" />
      <button type="submit" className="button is-link">Submit</button>
      <button onClick={handleResetClick} className="button is-link is-light">Clear</button>
    </form>
  )
}

function Field(props) {

  const {name, label, value, onChange} = props;
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">{label}</label>
        <div className="control">
          <input
            name={name}
            className="input"
            type="text"
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Form />
    </div>
  );
}
  
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at this earlier. You're probably right. The reason I wrote it the way I did was because there was some per-field validation I wanted to handle at the field level, rather than in the parent form. But I guess I can still pass the errors/new values up to the parent onChange and handle the state in the parent. I'll have another look.

Comment: If your forms get more complicated, or you want to take the burden off creating your own Field/Form components, I can recommend [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/) which is a lightweight form library that works well with React. It allows the use of [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) which might help with your validation issues.